# php- chmod(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I was trying to upload an image to a php server and from there send the image to parse.com using this documentation : https://parse.com/docs/rest#files

but the in parse , I can see only 0 sized images.  I am thinking that the problem is with file permission

so I tried to change the file permission.

```
            $target_path = "uploads/";
            $img =rand().basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
            $target_path=dirname(__FILE__)."/".$target_path.$img;
            print($target_path);
            chmod($target_path,0777);
```

but while executing this I am getting the following warning

`Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/test/new.php on line 15`

I can see the file in the uploads folder. and the owner of the file is www-data. any pointers

PS: Instead of absolute path I tried using relative paths also.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and is safe_mode on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are targeting the script file and not the PATH by doing '**FILE**'.

Use '**DIR**' and verify if the folder exist is_dir() before attempting permission verification.

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
$img =rand().basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
$target_path=dirname(__DIR__)."/".$target_path.$img;
print($target_path);
chmod($target_path,0777);
```